# Set a listener in react native in componentDidMount but dispatch to new screen not getting called

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the following problem. I have a class in react-native which more or less looks like this:

```
import {...};

const ReadyButton = props => (
  <View>
    <RoundButton
      width={175}
      text="..."
      onPress={props.onPress}
    />
  </View>
);

ReadyButton.propTypes = {
  onPress: PropTypes.func,
};

const ReadyButtonContainer = connect(null, dispatch => ({
  onPress: () => {
    dispatch(askIgnoreBatteryOptimizations(requestLocationPermissions));
  },
}))(ReadyButton);

export default class CalibrationWalkInstructions extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    listenToPermissionChanges();
  }

  render() {
    const enableBackgroundDataCollectionMessage = (Platform.OS === 'ios')
      ? '...'
      : '...';

    return (
      <ScreenWrapper>
        <CenterContent>
          <StandardWrapper spacing={15}>
            <FullWidthImage
              source={PhoneInPocketIconImage}
              width={300}
              height={380}
              scale={0.6}
            />
          </StandardWrapper>
          <StandardWrapper spacing={15}>
            <PrimaryText>
             ...
            </PrimaryText>
          </StandardWrapper>
          <StandardWrapper>
            <PrimaryText>
              {enableBackgroundDataCollectionMessage}
            </PrimaryText>
          </StandardWrapper>
          <ReadyButtonContainer />
        </CenterContent>
        <TutorialBottomProgress currentStep={2} stepName={'Walk'} align={'right'} />
      </ScreenWrapper>
    );
  }
};
```

Additionally I have a file called actions.js where all my functions are in. From here I want to call the following function which attaches a listener if the location permissions have been granted/changed in the iOS settings. The callback of the function will then directly lead the user to the next screen. My function in action.js looks like this so far:

```
export function listenToPermissionChanges() {
  console.log('FOOO listenToPermissionChanges called');
  return function(dispatch) {
    console.log('FOOO inside dispatch');
    listenToLocationPermissionChanges(function() {
      detachLocationPermissionChangeListener();
      console.log('FOOO dispatch now');
      dispatch({
        type: LOCATION_PERMISSION_GRANTED,
      });
      dispatch(goToWalkCalibration());
    });
  };
}
```

If I call this function in the componentDidMount() like above, I am able to reach to the first FOOO log statement but not further. My question is now, why does it not get further. Is there a problem that I can’t call a dispatch call from the componentDidMount() function, am I missing a return statement or why doesn’t it execute the rest but starts?

Thanks for the help / answers in advance.

Comment: Your `listenToPermissionChanges()` returns a second function (Currying). To execute both parts you need to execute `listenToPermissionChanges()(dispatch)` - For a very simple example, look here https://jsfiddle.net/arrbgbqn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the guy commented on the question. I solved it with `listenToPermissionChanges()(dispatch)`

Though it's somehow not possible to dispatch something in the `componentDidMount()` function. Therefore I just call the listenToPermissionChanges function on the ReadyButtonContainer. It looks like this now:

```
const ReadyButtonContainer = connect(null, dispatch => ({
  onPress: () => {
    dispatch(askIgnoreBatteryOptimizations(requestLocationPermissions));
    listenToPermissionChanges()(dispatch);
  },
}))(ReadyButton);
```